# call variabel result from one Methode into other Methode to use it in C

Tags: c

at school i have to make a Programm that calculated some Numbers in Different Methods, the different Methods are in relation to each other by a Variable.
here is a part of my code.

```
int pythagoras(double a, double b){

    
    double a2;
    double b2;
    double c2;
    double c =0.0;
    double wurzelc;
    
    a2 = pow(a,2);
    b2 = pow(b,2);
    c2 = a2 + b2;
    c = a + b;
    wurzelc = sqrt(c2);

    
    printf("a: %2.2f, a Quadrat: %2.2f \n",a, a2);
    printf("b: %2.2f, b Quadrat: %2.2f \n",b, b2);
    printf("c: %2.2f, c Quadrat: %2.2f, c Wurzel: %2.2f \n",c, c2, wurzelc);
    
    return 0;
}


int konvertradius(){

    
    double r2;
    double kflaeche;
    /*double r = 6.1;*/     
    double r = c;       //c is from "int pythagoras()"
    r2 = pow(r,2);
    kflaeche = M_PI * r2;

        printf("Kreisradius: %2.2f Flaecheninhalt:  %2.2f \n",r, kflaeche);

    return 0;
}
int main(){


    pythagoras(1.9, 4.2);
    konvertradius();

    
        return 0;
}
```

and now to my question, how can i get the result of variable "c" into the method "konvertradius()".

P.S: i am not allowed to use set and get.

Comment: Change the return type of the function and have `return c;` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Not.
While you are executing the other function, the local variable `c` in the `pythagoras()` does not exist.

For that variable to exist and have any value you would have to call that function. But at the point when it returns, the variable has already ceased to exist again.

What you could do is to move the code (which does the calculation of `c`) into a helper function which returns the result of the summing. That helper function could then be called from both the functions in which you want to use that calculation.

```
double helper(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b ;
}

int pythagoras(double a, double b)
{
    double a2;
    double b2;
    double c2;
    double c =0.0;
    double wurzelc;
    
    a2 = pow(a,2);
    b2 = pow(b,2);
    c2 = a2 + b2;
    c = helper(a,b);
    wurzelc = sqrt(c2);

    printf("a: %2.2f, a Quadrat: %2.2f \n",a, a2);
    printf("b: %2.2f, b Quadrat: %2.2f \n",b, b2);
    printf("c: %2.2f, c Quadrat: %2.2f, c Wurzel: %2.2f \n",c, c2, wurzelc);
    
    return 0;
}

int konvertradius(double a, double b)
{
    double r2;
    double kflaeche;
    /*double r = 6.1;*/     
    double r = helper(a,b);       //c is from "int pythagoras()"
    r2 = pow(r,2);
    kflaeche = M_PI * r2;

    printf("Kreisradius: %2.2f Flaecheninhalt:  %2.2f \n",r, kflaeche);

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    pythagoras(1.9, 4.2);
    konvertradius(1.9, 4.2);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, that in turn requires you to also provide the input data to the second function. Because there is no "use the same values, you know which I mean".
(Skipping the discussion of static variables inside functions, which do not help across different functions...)